# Check if key is held down, wxpython?

Tags: wxpython

Hello i am wondering if there is a way to check if a certain key is being held down.

Here is an example of the situation

```
self.button2.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.clickedbutton)
def clickedbutton(self, e):
    if (Control is held down while the button has been clicked):
        print "it works"
```

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest re-reading some of the answers.  Unless there's something I missed, one of the others than the accepted is cleaner, more portable, and works in my early tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with using only wx for this is that you need a KeyEvent to access the actual state of the control key. Since you need this information outside of such an event you need to keep track of it manually, and the problem with that is that it is easy to miss a KeyEvent since only focused controls get them and you can't count on them propagating.

The foolproof way would be to utilize some platform specific way of querying this information, if you are on windows look in to pyHook or win32api for this.

In some cases though the wx only approach can work and here is how you do it:

```
import wx


class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)

        btn = wx.Button(self, label="press me")
        self.Sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.Sizer.Add(btn)

        self.ctrl_down = False

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP, self.OnUpdateCtrlState)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnUpdateCtrlState)
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP, self.OnUpdateCtrlState)
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnUpdateCtrlState)
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton)

    def OnUpdateCtrlState(self, event):
        self.ctrl_down = event.ControlDown()
        print self.ctrl_down
        event.Skip()

    def OnButton(self, event):
        if self.ctrl_down:
            wx.MessageBox("control down")


app = wx.App(False)
app.TopWindow = f = Example()
f.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 9):

```
self.button2.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.clickedbutton)
def clickedbutton(self, e):
    if wx.GetKeyState(wx.WXK_CONTROL):
        print "it works"
```

Comment: This works in the wx apps I'm building, and seems correct. I can't help but wonder if this isn't either overlooked (your solution is much more direct and accessible than the accepted answer), or if there's some limitation somewhere that precludes this as the right answer. I up-voted, and intend to do some testing / research as well.

Comment: @g.d.d.c Hey thank you, this method is fine. The other answer was already accepted when I answered, which is why. Feel free to test though/research though, always a good idea :)

Comment: @g.d.d.c Ok just checked the [docs](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx-module.html#GetKeyState) _Get the state of a key (true if pressed or toggled on, false if not.) This is generally most useful getting the state of the modifier or toggle keys. **On some platforms those may be the only keys that this function is able to detect**._ I don't know what platforms it's referring to, but keys like Ctrl, alt etc (the modifier keys) should work well regardless according to this. I guess be careful if you're detecting regular keys with it.

Comment: This answer just saved me a lot of trouble! thanks a lot. On windows, I have no problem detecting a regular key.

Answer (score 0):

WxPython has a function wx.GetKeyState(key) that returns True if the key is currently down. It succeeds for all keys on Windows. But the documentation states that "In wxGTK, this function can be only used with modifier keys ( WXK_ALT , WXK_CONTROL and WXK_SHIFT ) when not using X11 backend currently".

Here is a portable alternative. It uses a filter function as part of the App to filter all events. It captures the key up and key down events. It can be extended to other events.

```
class App(wx.App):
    def __init__(self):
        self.keys_down = []
    def FilterEvent(self, event):
        typ = event.GetEventType()
        if typ == wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN.typeId:
            key = event.GetKeyCode()  # This is always upper case
            if key not in self.keys_down:
                self.keys_down.append(key)
                print (self.keys_down)
        elif typ == wx.EVT_KEY_UP.typeId:
            key = event.GetKeyCode()
            self.keys_down.remove(key)
            print (self.keys_down)
        return -1
    def QuiskGetKeyState(self, key): # Replacement for wx.GetKeyState()
        if 97 <= key <= 122:    # convert to upper case
            key -= 32
        return key in self.keys_down
```